# Present a map of the company locations to establishes trust amongst first time visitors?

Tags: user-behavior, map-ui

In the sample user journey, say that a user encounters a product such as high price commercial equipment.

Before contacting the company, the user might want to know more about the company. More importantly that the company is reputable and not a fly-by-night or some internet company out of a guys garage, or a foreign company with an unreliable service team.

Let's say that the user is from Los Angeles and the manufacturer is from San Francisco, CA. Users visit the web site and want to know that they are visiting a reputable local company which provide service if needed.

So I am thinking of information in the footer, using the contact info along with a small map. Under that have a button that says "local service reps" which redirects to a map with pinpoints to the service reps.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear about the question...unless you're asking how to show local service rep's on a map?

Comment: @DA01, so allow me to give another example. Say you were looking for a commercial printer, and you live in San Francisco. 

And say a concern of your was, "what happens when I need service."

Well what if on the manufacturers website, we mentioned that the manufacturer and the service centers are very close to you AND that we have your area covered.

Comment: I'd say that's a good thing. Show a map of local service representatives.

Comment: just my two cents: be sure to have the map branded (CI) and don't use gxxgle maps or any other 'free' tool

Comment: @tillinberlin why do you suggest that? I'd consider Google maps completely reputable (and expected).

Comment: @tillinberlin I love that idea. I am thinking CartoDB because they offer very attractive options with very customizable information that can be presented to the user.

Comment: @DA01 I was having the key words "high price commercial equipment" and "that the company is reputable" in my mind - for me a map using company CI-Elements such as colors and fonts would be most convincing

Comment: As this is a UX site, I'd have to argue that using what people are familiar with is a good thing. People are familiar with Google maps. They trust Google maps. That's not to say another map service might be useful/applicable, but I wouldn't say 'high priced equipment' equates to having to use non-standard map software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should show a sideshow of nice office photos, and show a small map to present multiple locations of offices. Customers see picture and understand that your company is big and has many employees.

https://foursquare.com/jobs/

I think there are a problem that you show whole US map,but you have two offices on the map. Customers may feel that you have less coverage of service area,and you waste a lot of space on your site. However, if a company have many branches, you can show on the map. The map will assist customers to visits the locations.

http://m.louisvuitton.com/mobile/eng_US/Stores/Store-Locator

Comment: Nice example with Louis Vuitton. They also gave me the idea of having language option, search features, and to subtly have links in the footer to direct you back to relevant parts of the website.

Comment: I am appreciated that the example can help you. This is another good example. https://maps.google.com/ and https://foursquare.com/explore?near=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&q=Food

Comment: Yes, Foursquare is awesome. They use the MapBox API to power their maps. More info on that service is available at [www.mapbox.com/developers/](http://mapbox.com/developers/)

Comment: I think Google map is good for low traffic website, but for high traffic like Foursquare, you may need to host OpenStreet map. http://blog.foursquare.com/2012/02/29/foursquare-is-joining-the-openstreetmap-movement-say-hi-to-pretty-new-maps/

Comment: http://www.bing.com/maps/ is an alternative map. Facebook uses the Bing map.

Answer (score 2):

A map would definatly do the trick here - or even better - a clickable map where you can chose service center directly from the map - such as the one [Sony](http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/services.servicesprograms.bbsccms-services-servicesprograms-servicecenterlocations.shtml) uses:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you also have information about existing customers and their address you could also include a bit more information to the map to add credibility. Let's say "5 customers that live in your city have service with us." It is similar idea that [Angie's List](http://www.angieslist.com/)  website uses; they tell you how many neighbors received service from a business.

Comment: Oh cool I love the concept because it shows validation from locals!